# MongoDB sorting nested array of objects by object property value

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Hello i am new in MongoDB and NodeJS. How can i sort this array of objects for example by ELO, GAMES_COUNT, TIME, users firstname etc. with MongoDB mongoose aggregate ?

Here is an examle:

```
"statistics": [
{"statistics": [
        {
          "type": "ELO",
          "value": 1022
        },
        {
          "type": "GAMES_COUNT",
          "value": 5
        },
        {
          "type": "TIME",
          "value": 3112
        },
      ],
      "user": {
        "_id": "1",
        "firstName": "Pepa",
        "lastName": "Novák",
      }
    },
    {
      "statistics": [
        {
          "type": "ELO",
          "value": 1028
        },
        {
          "type": "GAMES_COUNT",
          "value": 4
        },
        {
          "type": "TIME",
          "value": 2151
        },
      ],
      "user": {
        "_id": "2",
        "firstName": "Václav",
        "lastName": "Rupinsky"
      }
    }
    ]
```

Comment: did you try Array.sort()?